# ColdFusion 9: Login skip prevention

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have been unable to find the solution to this issue.

I have my Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
<cfscript>
    this.name = "Login";
    this.applicationtimeout = "#createtimespan(0,0,20,0)#";
    this.sessionManagement = true;
    this.sessiontimeout = "#createtimespan(0,0,20,0)#";
    this.setClientCookies = true;
    this.setDomainCookies = false;
    this.scriptProtect = "all";
</cfscript>


<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returntype="boolean">

    <cfreturn True />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onSessionStart">
    <cfscript>
        Session.Login = false;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And I have added these lines of code to try and prevent going directly to the page:

```
<cfif NOT Session.Login>
<cflocation url="login.cfm" addtoken="no" />
</cfif>
```

And yet I just keep getting an error saying "Element LOGIN is undefined in SESSION." 
Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you `cfdump` session? Is login there? You could also fix your issue by saying `<cfif NOT structKeyExists(session, 'login') OR NOT session.login>`

Comment: Where is that check being done?

Comment: Made a seperate cfm:
    <cfdump var="#Session.Login#">
This returns False as it should.

Comment: I have found the main issue now. The redirect works but after pressing my logout button it no longer works.This is my logout button:`<cfinput type="button" onClick="location='logout.cfm'" name="Logout" value="Logout">` which calls this short cfm:`<cfset StructClear(Session)>
<cfset StructDelete(Session, 'Login', False)>
<cflocation url="login.cfm" addtoken="no" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you did ANY testing of your app before you added onSessionStart, then your session is already begun and it won't run. You can force the app to restart by using ApplicationStop(), restarting CF (lame, but works), or even renaming the app (more lame, but I've done it).